# Scala Cats FreeMonad - Why do I need asInstanceOf[Id[A]] in my Interpreter?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, free-monad

I have a toy example of FreeMonads using `cats-free` and my FunctorTransformer (i.e. the Interpreter) from my algebra (`sealed trait StartupActionA[T]`) to `Id[A]` seems to require and explicit call to `asInstanceOf[Id[A]]`.

See https://github.com/rodoherty1/FreeMonads/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/rob/FreeMonads.scala#L45

According to the [Cats documentation](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html), I should not need this explicit call to `asInstanceOf[Id[A]]`.

This is my algebra:

```
sealed trait StartupActionA[A] extends Product with Serializable
case object StartCluster extends StartupActionA[Unit]
case object StartEventActorShard extends StartupActionA[ActorRef]
case class StartKafka(ref: ActorRef) extends StartupActionA[Option[ActorRef]]
```

And this is my interpreter:

```
object Interpreter extends (StartupActionA ~> Id) {

  override def apply[A](fa: StartupActionA[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
    case StartCluster =>
      println("Starting up the Akka Cluster").asInstanceOf[A]
    case StartEventActorShard =>
      system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor()), "MyActor").asInstanceOf[A]
    case StartKafka(ref) =>
      Some(ref).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

Am I missing an implicit conversion or have I defined my algebra incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algebra is fine, don't be misguided by IDEA.

Here is a small reproduce without using Akka, which compiles with Scala 2.12.4 and cats-1.0.0-RC1:

```
import cats.{Id, ~>}

sealed trait StartupActionA[A] extends Product with Serializable
case object StartCluster extends StartupActionA[Unit]
case object StartEventActorShard extends StartupActionA[String]
case class StartKafka(ref: String) extends StartupActionA[Option[String]]

object Interpreter extends (StartupActionA ~> Id) {
  override def apply[A](fa: StartupActionA[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
    case StartCluster => ()
    case StartEventActorShard => "hello"
    case StartKafka(ref) => Some(ref)
  }
}
```

Although IDEA yells with red squiggles.

Comment: I think I know where I was going wrong here - my types were just a bit messed up and I was incorrectly assuming that I could return a value of any type and expect it to be automatically cast to `[A]`.  Nothing fancy going on here - just a silly mistake on my part.  
However you're answer was helpful because IntelliJ was incorrectly reporting compile errors.  Thank you!

Comment: *return a value of any type and expect it to be automatically cast to [A]* You return what your free monad extends. i.e. `case object StartEventActorShard extends StartupActionA[String]` must return a `String`.